# Multilist with Search not working with Powershell script

Tags: powershell-extensions

When we use "Multilist with Search" as editor option using powershell extension, it shows multilist without any search. It seems the multilist with search is not enabled.

I used below line of code in my powershell script

```
@{ Name = "multilistwithsearch";  Title="MultilistDemo"; 
  Source="StartSearchLocation={CC4E9B0A-17B2-4D78-917A-419620A80D06}&TemplateFilter={18050423-3FCF-4AAC-ACA4-B2EEA541000B}"; 
  editor="multilist with Search";             
     }
```

Can some one tell us that multilist with search is enabled with powershell extension? If yes then could someone show how to configure it?

Comment: Have you tested out the kitcken sink demo for `Read-Variable`? Check out the Getting Started module which contains a `Read-Variable` example that demonstrates all the available options. I suspect as of 4.7 there is only support for multilist without search. See the editor types listed here https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/interactive-dialogs.html

Comment: I got the answer from The portal when I posted this a bug. Here is the answer.
"Unfortunately, the Multilist with Search is not supported in the current version. I did however make some adjustments which would enable the support in a future version, probably 4.8".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from The portal when I posted this a bug.

Unfortunately, the Multilist with Search is not supported in the current version. I did however make some adjustments which would enable the support in a future version, probably 4.8.